# Infinite computer reboot loop when the Ubuntu disk inserted

Tags: boot, system-installation

I am currently using Windows 8.1.
I want to install Ubuntu as a dual boot. I burned the disk and put it in the drive and rebooted. Ubuntu first loads some things, then shows a little insignia at the bottom after which it just shows a black screen with a rapidly blinking cursor. 
After about a minute the computer reboots and the process continues until the disk is removed.

I tried both Ubuntu 13.10 and 12.04, both gave the same result.

I have left the computer with the disk in for about an hour, during which it constantly looped.

Answer (score 0):

It takes some time to load all the things that are needed from the disk before Ubuntu can actually start up. It takes even more time if you are using a disk instead of a USB stick (quicker access on flash memory).

Did you try to wait more than one minute ?

Also can you make sure that your Ubuntu image (the one that you burnt on the disk) is not corrupted ?

I would try to boot from a flash drive just to make sure it is not related to memory access. See [this guide](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows) to create your bootable stick.

Answer (score 0):

Some windows 8 computers have to use advanced startup to boot off a cd or usb drive.

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/windows-startup-settings-including-safe-mode